# How to catch user search in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to create an extension for catching the query string of the user search.

If it matches with a certain string, then show the results in the regular template; if not, show them in another layout.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you start anything?

Comment: No, I'm very new in Magento extension devel and I don't really know which class to extend.

Comment: Instead of posting question you can try magento tutorials

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, especially because I'm searching for this since weeks...

Answer (score 0):

Magento stored customer query in database you can use that table and get your result. you can also get customer query in Magento backend at `Catalog >> Search Term`

Comment: Ok, but how do I catch the search? I need a hook to get the query string when the user makes a search.